# Where can I find Android's new features

Tags: android

Android has so many features such as PUSH NOTIFICATIONS....

Can anyone point me at the place where the new and updated features are documented. I am new to android and want to know about new features in order to improve my programming skills.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3):

Just check this page when a new version comes out , they list all the new features and differences: http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.2.html

Answer (score 1):

Just check [android developer DevGuide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) in this site you will get all features of android.
and you want to check new features then check [android blog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) in this page you will get recently updated for android.